# Call to a member function setLayer() on a non-object

Tags: php, magento

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setLayer() on a non-object in
>   /home/content/74/10047874/html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/View.php
>   on line 135

```
 $this->setChild($attribute->getAttributeCode() . '_filter',
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock($filterBlockName)
                ->setLayer($this->getLayer())
                ->setAttributeModel($attribute)
                ->init());
```

> Please help me out of this

Comment: The error is here: `$this->getLayout()->createBlock($filterBlockName)->setLayer($this->getLayer()` - createBlock function doesn't return the object.

Comment: Can you debug the value of `$filterBlockName` when the error occurs ?

Comment: Looks like your block is not set.

Comment: Yest @blmage i did like this. echo '|'.$filterBlockName.'|'; value is getting.

Answer (score -2):

Try to comment out the whole code for the particular page.

OR

put that whole code in if condition for that particular page.

For example if error is displayed in cms home page than do like this.

```
if(Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier() == 'home' && Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'cms')
{}
else
         {
         $this->setChild($attribute->getAttributeCode() . '_filter',
             $this->getLayout()->createBlock($filterBlockName)
                 ->setLayer($this->getLayer())
                 ->setAttributeModel($attribute)
                 ->init());
         }
```

Comment: Its better to check for other conflicting extension before you out the code like above.